# Help! My Rasperry Pi Camera is not being detected!

Tags: camera

So I have a Pi-Cam and a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and I'm trying to get them to work together. Note: This camera has worked many times before today's errors.

A few things:

- The voltage is fine (red light is constantly on)
- The camera is plugged into the CSI port (in between HDMI and Ethernet)
- The metal strips on the camera are facing towards the HDMI port
- I've tested the camera with another raspberry pi, but I'd like to use it with this Pi.
- The camera is enabled from sudo raspi-config > Interfacing > Camera

The CSI connector (that little white piece at the top) is a bit broken and will
fall off quiet readily if the camera is not attached. Would this be an issue?

Here's the error when I run `raspistill -o image.jpg`:

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647  
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)  
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)  
mmal: Failed to create camera component  
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component  
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

**Is there anything else that I could try to get this camera to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check  `vcgencmd get_camera`  this command. It will return how many cameras supported and detected. Normally you will get `supported=1` and`detected=1`. If you get `detected=0` then camera not detected.
2. Recheck hardware connection.
3. Try setting `gpu_mem=128` in `/boot/config.txt`
4. Enable I2C interface.

If not work, try with a different camera.

Comment: 4 is not necessary, but /boot/config.txt should contain `start_x=1`. Or just enable the camera in raspi-config... BTW If `enabled=1` then gpu_mem and start_x are fine (otherwise `enabled` would fail)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I eventually relented and switched to a different camera.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, all head-scratching and googling did no good. Then I saw that the raspberry pi 4b board has **2** flatcable connectors - clearly marked as "display" and "camera". The first (Display) sits at the edge opposite the USB-block, the second (camera) right beside the A/V connector.
Plugging the camera flatcable into the right connector magically solved all my problems. It's worth a check !
No idea how one can be that blind....
Hopefully this helps one or the other mate !

Kind regards

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Try `vcgencmd get_camera` to get the status of the camera, if you see detected = 0 open the "Raspberry Pi configuratios" in preferences menu and enable the Camera along with I2C, reboot and it should work.

Comment: Where can I see `detected = 0`?

Comment: use vcgencmd get_camera

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above on a reset of the preferences - It now works.

Oddly, detected = 0 is still shown but camera = 1.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

"Try vcgencmd get_camera to get the status of the camera, if you see detected = 0 open the "Raspberry Pi configuratios" in preferences menu and enable the Camera along with I2C, reboot and it should work."

Comment: change that. only w\]orked once

Answer (score 0):

I have detected = 0 and supported = 0 what's does it mean supported 0 ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134556)